# string comparison and macro OR condition

Tags: m4

In M4 language, is there a way that I can compare a string argument to two values and if any of those two match, then X is executed, other Y is executed?

For example, if argument to MACTEST macro is either 'ABC' or 'XYZ', then 'match' is shown, otherwise 'nomatch' is shown...Looks like eval is for comparing numeric arguments and not for strings..Is there something equivalent for string?

```
define(MACTEST, ifelse(eval($1==ABC)|eval($1==XYZ), 1, match, nomatch)')

MACTEST(ABC)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities (underquoted for clarity):

```
define(MACTEST,`ifelse($1,ABC,match,$1,XYZ,match,no-match)')dnl
define(MACTEST,`ifelse(regexp($1,ABC\|XYZ),-1,no-match,match)')dnl
```